# preg replace regex extract string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'm trying to extract the **3BF50B3A9BCB2BC8E40256F30B7F2C22** token from this string.

```
$longtext="rt%3D280'; HdfJson['postToken'] = '3BF50B3A9BCB2BC8E40256F30B7F2C22';HdfJson['googleUrlHl'] =";

$token=preg_replace("/(\[\'postToken']\s\=\s)(\'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\')(\;)/u","$2",$longtext);
echo $token;
```

---

the resultat was like this:

```
rt%3D280'; HdfJson['postToken'] =  HdfJson['googleUrlHl'] =
```

how to extract just the **token**?

Comment: Since you only want to extract something, `preg_match` is more appropriate than `preg_replace` *(that is used for replacements)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to match also the preceeding and following characters by `.*` so that only the whole line would be replaced by the group you specified.

```
.*(?:\[\'postToken']\s\=\s)\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\';.*
|                                             |
Here                                        Here
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wB3fW0/3)

Code:

```
<?php
$longtext="rt%3D280'; HdfJson['postToken'] = '3BF50B3A9BCB2BC8E40256F30B7F2C22';HdfJson['googleUrlHl'] =";
$token=preg_replace("~.*(?:\[\'postToken']\s\=\s)\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\';.*~u","$1",$longtext);
echo $token;
?>
```

Output:

```
3BF50B3A9BCB2BC8E40256F30B7F2C22
```

Comment: yep. The main thing is you need to add `.*` before and after. I just modified your regex and posted it as solution. You could modify mine according to your needs. I spot out the problem already.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use preg_replace to do that, if you want to extract something from a string without modify it, the function to use is `preg_match`. Example:

```
$str = "rt%3D280'; HdfJson['postToken'] = '3BF50B3A9BCB2BC8E40256F30B7F2C22';HdfJson['googleUrlHl'] =";

$re = '/\QHdfJson['postToken'] = '\E([[:xdigit:]]+)';/';
                               //   ↑_____________↑             
if (preg_match($re, $str, $m)) //         |
    $token = $m[1]; // first capturing group
```

Between `\Q` and `\E` all special characters are ignored *(except the pattern delimiter)*. It is useful to copy/paste a literal string into a pattern without asking too much questions about what must be escaped or not. *(For the info, only `[` needs to be escaped)*

The `[:xdigit:]` character class contains only hexadecimal characters. But if you want to be more rigorous, you can change it to `[A-F0-9]` that doesn't contain `[a-f]`.